System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll is both a Nuget package and in the Desktop runtime
I'm working on the installer for a .NET 8.0 Windows Desktop app.  Do I need to add this DLL in my installer?
I thought I would need to add Nuget DLL's to the installer but the loaded modules shows Microsoft DLL's from C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\8.0.x that are clearly Nuget packages.
How do I know what I need to install vs the Microsoft .NET installed files?
